# “Go outside” vs “go out”

Tags: word-usage, difference

I miss going outside.
I miss going out.

I assume that these two sentences have a slight difference in the meaning.
My image of “to go outside”, is for example, I go outside of my house and spend some time in the nature. Or to just go outside of my house for a short amount of time. “I am going outside to throw out the trash.”

“Go out” feels like to go and hang out with friends, go shopping, going metc.

Can they be used interchangeably?

This is just how I feel about these two phrases, so if I’m mistaken, please correct me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Out Of The Office, Outside The Office](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28960/out-of-the-office-outside-the-office)

Comment: Perhaps more specifically, Does ***this*** answer your question? [Should I say "go out" or "go outside"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36831/should-i-say-go-out-or-go-outside)

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

*You say 'go out' when you're either going somewhere with friends or when you're in a relationship you're going out with your partner.*

**For example:**

-I'm just going out for a walk. Do you want to come?

-She has been going out with him for ages.

*'Go outside' means go outside like out of your home, room etc.*

**For example:**

-I'm going outside to see if it's raining.